# Proving Linkedness of Hopf Fibers

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, quaternions, hopf-fibration

So I've been working on understanding the Hopf fibration in terms of quaternions for the past few months, following along with the investigations in David Lyon's paper, "[An Elementary Introduction to the Hopf Fibration"](https://nilesjohnson.net/hopf-articles/Lyons_Elem-intro-Hopf-fibration.pdf). I've done a good job getting through almost the entirety of the paper, until I get to the last investigation: Investigation (M).

The Hopf fibration is a mapping from $S^3 \mapsto S^2$ such that the preimage of a point on $S^2$ is a circle (fiber) in $S^3$. The previous investigation, which I already did successfully, shows that these fibers, when stereographically projected, are linked with the unit circle in the $yz$-plane. This is simple enough. Here is investigation (M):

> To show that any two projected fiber circles $C$ and $D$
>   are linked, we exhibit a continuous one-to-one map $\psi: \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ that takes $C$ to the unit circle in the $y, z$-plane, and takes $D$ to some other projected fiber circle $E$. Since $E$ is linked with the unit circle in the $y, z$-plane, $C$ and $D$ must also be linked. See Figure 9. (Students who have never studied topology may accept the intuitively reasonable statement that linked-ness of circles cannot be altered by a continuous bijective map. Students with experience in topology may enjoy trying to prove this.) Here is how to construct the map $\psi$. Let $P$ be any point on the circle $C$, and let $r = s^{−1}(P)$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ by $f(x) = kr^{−1}x$ (quaternion multiplication). The map $\psi$ is the composition $s \circ f \circ s^{−1}$.

Just for some background:

$s$ is the stereographic projection map given by $$(w,x,y,z) \mapsto \left(\frac{x}{1-w}, \frac{y}{1-w}, \frac{z}{1-w} \right)$$
where $(w,x,y,z)$ is the vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ associated with the quaternion given by the Hopf map. A long investigation previous to this (Investigation (J)) explains that these quaternions are $h^{-1}(P) = \{r_1 e^{it}\}_{0\leq t \leq 2\pi}$ where $P$ is any point on $S^2$. **This is not the same P as the one on the fiber in Investigation M**.

So this is how I'm thinking about the problem:

I understand that if we can construct a continuous map that takes 2 fibers and sends one to the unit circle in the $yz$-plane, then we have shown that since all fibers are linked with the unit circle, and continuous maps don't break linked-ness, then the fibers must be linked with each other. The part I can't get is actually proving this.

Instead of creating a fiber, I just took a specific quaternion corresponding with a particular fiber and defined that as $r = s^{-1}(P)$. If you apply $s(f(r))$, you end up with $k$. Then I picked another point on that fiber and used the *same* $r^{-1}$ to calculate $f$, but the algebra ended up really messy and I wasn't getting anywhere. I know what should follow is a unit circle, but I don't think I'm approaching the problem correctly, because it seems overly tedious.

Does anyone have any thoughts about how to prove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know the paper and in fact, the author made a mistake in the homeomorphism $\psi$ that is supposed to take two fibers to the unit circle and some other fiber. Also, I feel it is somewhat overcomplicated.

Construct the map from scratch. First, we demand that for fibers $C, D$ the fiber $C$ is sent to the fiber over $(-1, 0, 0)$, which is the unit circle under stereographic projection. Guess that $\psi$ is of the form $\psi(x):=\rho x$ where $\rho$ is some unit Quaternion since this simple map will take great circles to great circles (not necessarily fibers though, that needs to be proved separately!).

Calculate
$$
 h(\psi(C)) = (\rho C) i \overline{(\rho C)} = \rho C i \overline{C} \overline{\rho} = \rho h(C) \rho^{-1}
$$
and recognize the Quaternion rotation (in the paper, this was another investigation).

To satisfy our demands, $\rho$ must therefore rotate $\mathbb R^3$ such that $h(C)$ is sent to $(-1, 0, 0)$. Now, use the construction of the Hopf-fibration as presented in the paper. By it, we know for any $r\in C$ we have $rh(C)\bar r = (1, 0, 0)$. Now we simply rotate by $k$ afterwards to get to $(-1, 0, 0)$ as desired. Together this yields $\rho = kr$. This is the mistake in the paper.

This yields $h(\psi(C)) = k(rh(C)\bar r)\bar k = (-1, 0, 0)$ and you can satisfy yourself, that $h(\psi(D))$ is a well-defined point so that $\psi$ also sent $D$ to another fiber.